# React Native | Passing hook between functions

Tags: react-native

I want to pass a hook value from one function to another.

Hook

```
function BuildingHighlight(){

const [buildingName, setBuildingName] = React.useState("");

 return (
    <View>
        <Polygon
            coordinates={coord.h.coordinates}
            tappable={true}
            onPress={() => setBuildingName("Hall Building")}
            fillColor="rgba(76, 79, 98, 0.7)"
        />
 )
}
```

If I need the buildingName value in another file, how can I get it?

Comment: There are multiple ways to get that value such as pass value as navigation params, store value in AsyncStorage or use redux or context API.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned my @SDushan there are multiple ways to achieve this the best one being redux 
but if you don't want to use redux you can opt a simple method which is included in [reactn](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn#readme) called useGlobal you can follow the [Medium tutorial here](https://dev.to/charlesstover/manage-global-state-with-react-hooks-2692)